# Is there a way to transmit all sound over wifi from my tablet to my pc?

Tags: audio, streaming, 3.0-honeycomb

I want to transmit my sound (from youtube, music files on the tablet, etc) from my tablet to my computer.

The closest I can get is controlling my library of music on my computer, but I really want to be able to play a youtube video from the youtube app on my tablet and have it play through my computer.

I don't mind buying apps if that is what I need. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use the youtube app to get where you want to go but there are a quite a few DLNA (google it) based alternatives out there which could be what you are looking for. I am currently evaluating some of them but my objective is a little bit different and probably the toolset as well. Good luck, maybe someone else have good app suggestions.

Comment: I'm assuming by the title that you don't want to use bluetooth? It only goes ~30ft, but it's fairly simple and works well in most scenarios. Your laptop most likely supports A2DP, and thus you don't need to buy or download anything.

Comment: Oh, and A2DP supports controls such as play/pause/skip/volume, which is a nice bonus.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is at the moment impossible to stream all audio from your android to another receiver.

There's no app which can help you because android itself has no APIs for grabbing audio.

But sure you may use a specific player, e.g. one for YouTube and one for music and so on.

I really know what I'm talking about because I'm developing an app for general streaming audio since several months (it's really hard work with rooting, kernel-module etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into [Plex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexapp.android&hl=en). I have never used it, but I hear it is good and works on a multitude of devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a solution for you but to conserve my processing power for gaming I stream movies on my tablet right beside me while I play and at night I'd like to listen to all of my audio through my USB headphones. I plugged a dual-sided 1/8th inch jack into my tablet and the microphone port on my computer, go into Sound>Recording Devices, right click on the proper device, go to properties, Listen, then check the "Listen to this device" and apply. Occasionally I'll get a weird feedback noise but it's solved my problem and I hope it can help anyone else looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For the Youtube specific part of your request specifically, Google have released an official [YouTube Remote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.ytremote) app, that allows you to control playing YouTube videos on a PC from an Android phone/tablet. You visit http://youtube.com/leanback on your PC, and the app then interacts with it.